# "SetEnv" via php.ini file

Tags: php, fuelphp, setenv

I'm using FuelPHP and the environment information cannot be passed to my command-line script via the framework htaccess file.  I read that I can set the same value by modifying my php.ini file.  I'm using XAMPP on my localhost, but it doesn't seem to be working -- getenv('FUEL_ENV') returns nothing.  I am missing something.

```
SetEnv FUEL_ENV production
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SetEnv` is an Apache directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv); it goes in a .htaccess file or your server config files, not in php.ini.